# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrival>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been writing test for GetConcreteNumberTrival class and it shows the above error at this statement:

```
when(mockNumberTrivalRepository.getConcreteNumberTrival(number: tNumber))
          .thenAnswer((_) async{
        return right(numberTrival);
      });
```

full code: get_concrete_number_trival_test.dart

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/core/failure/failure.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/entities/number_trival.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/repositories/number_trival_repository.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/usecases/get_concrete_number_trival.dart';

// we create abstract of NumberTrivalRepo because GetConcreteNumberTrival
// use NumberTrivalRepository to get data. So, we mock it to use it
// as per our need
class MockNumberTrivalRepository extends Mock
    implements NumberTrivalRepository {}


void main() {
  late MockNumberTrivalRepository mockNumberTrivalRepository;
  late GetConcreteNumberTrival sut;

  setUp(() {
    mockNumberTrivalRepository = MockNumberTrivalRepository();
    sut = GetConcreteNumberTrival(mockNumberTrivalRepository);
    print("initialize");
  });

  final numberTrival = NumberTrival(text: "text", number: 4);
  int tNumber = 4;

  test(
    "get concrete number trivial",
    () async {
      when(mockNumberTrivalRepository.getConcreteNumberTrival(number: tNumber))
          .thenAnswer((_) async{
        return right(numberTrival);
      });
      final result = await sut.execute(tNumber);

      expect(result, right(numberTrival));
      verify(
          mockNumberTrivalRepository.getConcreteNumberTrival(number: tNumber));
    },
  );
}
```

NumberTrivalRepository class:

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/entities/number_trival.dart';

import '../../../../core/failure/failure.dart';

abstract class NumberTrivalRepository {
  

  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrival>> getConcreteNumberTrival(
      {required int number});
  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrival>> getRandomNumberTrival();
}
```

GetConcreteNumberTrival class:

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/core/failure/failure.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/entities/number_trival.dart';
import 'package:number_trivia/features/number_trivia/domain/repositories/number_trival_repository.dart';

class GetConcreteNumberTrival {
  NumberTrivalRepository repository;

  GetConcreteNumberTrival(this.repository);

  Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrival>> execute(int number) async {
    return await repository.getConcreteNumberTrival(number: number);
  }
}
```

I spend my whole day solving this but cannot get it. Helping hands is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) instead of *mockito*. Your test function will look like this:

```
 test(
    "get concrete number trivial",
    () async {
      when(() => mockNumberTrivalRepository.getConcreteNumberTrival(
          number: tNumber)).thenAnswer((_) {
        return right(numberTrival);
      });
      final result = await sut.execute(tNumber);

      expect(result, right(numberTrival));
      verify(() =>
          mockNumberTrivalRepository.getConcreteNumberTrival(number: tNumber));
    },
  );
```

I have tested it, and it works well

Comment: no it doesn't solve the error